# out of box example does not work on python 3.3 expected bytes str found

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa

```
from rsa import *

def main():
    (bob_pub,bob_pri)=newkeys(512)
    message ='Number of bits needed to represent a integer'
    crypto = encrypt(message,bob_pub)
    message1 = decrypt(crypto,bob_pri)
    print(message1)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

hi everyone im new to site this is my first post

ive installed python 3.3 here is a pip list of my installation

```
C:\Python33>pip list
beautifulsoup4 (4.3.2)
mechanize (0.2.5)
mpmath (0.18)
pip (1.5)
pyasn1 (0.1.7)
pyLibrary (0.1.13316)
PyMySQL (0.6.1)
requests (2.2.0)
rsa (3.1.2)
setuptools (2.1)

C:\Python33>
```

The rsa documentation for an example program is the same as the code sample but I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\my code\rsa hacker.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python33\my code\rsa hacker.py", line 6, in main
    crypto = encrypt(message,bob_pub)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 166, in encrypt
    padded = _pad_for_encryption(message, keylength)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 106, in _pad_for_encryption
    message])
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected bytes, str found
```

this code should work I have checked it is 3.3 compatible and my installation seems fine
im not sure where to go from this. do try another rsa package do change to 2.7 or is it an installation problem please could someone explain in very basic steps

Comment: I don't know anything about rsa encryption in python, nor the packages involved, but the error message basically says "I expected bytes to encrypt, but you gave me a string". Could you try converting the message you're encrypting to bytes? (which I would not know how to do). Perhaps run it through some encoding object or something.

Comment: I have looked into that but all my test programs at converting fail as well. Does any one know how to do this so that I may learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `message` is actually a string (`str`). It happens to be an ASCII string and thus could look to you as a byte string. It is not; it could be `'Привет 世界'` as well. Representation of strings is a complex matter; there's no single natural characters-to-bytes transform.

What you need is `message.encode('utf-8')` (or choose another encoding). This is your strings encoded as a UTF-8 array of bytes which the encoder expects.

After decoding, you will need `message1.decode('urf-8')` to get the original test back.

Comment: I have just tried your suggestion but it does not seem to make any difference. are there other encodings that would work?

Comment: @flipflop: 9000 is right.  Your code works for me with the line `crypto = encrypt(message.encode("utf-8"),bob_pub)` instead.

Comment: first I tried `message=message.encode('utf-8')` but your suggestion does work whats the difference?